# Grouping modules in Intellij IDEA does not affect Project tab

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a multi module Java project in `Intellij IDEA 15.0.2`

I just tried to group modules to organize them but in the `Project` tab I have flat view of my project and there in no change after all!!!

My modules just grouped inside the `Project Structure` panel.

Is there any way to show modules as group view inside the `Project` tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realized that this is not applicable using current versions of Intellij IDEA.